# FormView C# Toggle Image Visibility

Tags: c#, image, formview

I have a FormView that displays a Button and an image.
When the user clicks the linkButton, I want to show/hide the visibility of image.

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormOptions" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="dsOpts" ForeColor="#333333">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonHide" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("optDisplay")%>' onclick="ButtonHide_Click"/>
<asp:Image ID="ImageFP" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("optImage")%>' runat="server" CssClass="optImages"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Then in my code behind, I have:

```
protected void ButtonHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ImageFP.visible = false;
}
```

However, I get an error saying it cannot find ImageFP.  This works when the image is not part of a FormView so I'm guessing I need to specify more directly the path to the image.  I'm new with Visual Basic and appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a refrence to the image inside the item template of the Form view 
like the following

```
protected void ButtonHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Image tmp = (Image)FormView1.FindControl("ImageFP");
tmp.Visible = !(tmp.Visible);// this will toggle the visibility 

}
```